# How to compare columns with count from different tables?

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have three tables: person, message and hasfriend. Now I need to show every person that has the same amount of friends and sent messages.

Person has the info of everyone, most importantly the email. Message has a column called "fromemail", which shows the person that sent the message and hasfriend also has a column "email" which refers to the table person.

Comment: Please **[edit]** your question (by clicking on the [edit] link below it) and add some [sample data](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/81852) and the expected output based on that data. [Formatted text](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/251362) please, [no screen shots](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-may-i-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question/285557#285557). ([edit] your question - do **not** post code or additional information in comments)

Answer (score 0):

You could try somethink like:

```
SELECT p1.email, p2.email
FROM
    (SELECT email, count(message_id) m_count, count(friend_id) f_count
        FROM
            person p
            JOIN message m ON p.email = m.email
            JOIN hasfriend f ON p.email = f.email) p1,
    (SELECT email, count(message_id) m_count, count(friend_id) f_count
        FROM
            person p
            JOIN message m ON p.email = m.email
            JOIN hasfriend f ON p.email = f.email) p2
WHERE
    p1.email = p2.email AND
    p1.m_count = p2.m_count AND
    p1.f_count = p2.f_count;
```